# Logging real time from .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

.bat file

```
FOR %%A in (*.css) DO ( 
@echo %date% %time% >>log.txt
pause

)
```

writes always the same time to log file.
It looks like %time% is evaluated only once.

How to write real time to log file ?
Using Windows 10

Comment: Delay the expansion of the variable, or use `Call`.

Comment: What exactly to change ?

Comment: As it very clearly states in the accepted answer of the linked question, add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to the top of the script and then change `%date% %time%` to `!date! !time!`.

Comment: Thank you, It worked. You may wrote this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see why the code is behaving like this, you need to remove the "@" in front of the echo. The code that gets executed is for example:

```
FOR %A in (*.css) DO (
  echo 30.03.2020 19:20:57,99  1>>log.txt
  pause
)
```

because everything in the brackets () is treated as one line, so the variables date and time are replaced by their current values before the loop gets executed.

To get an unique timestamp for every file, you need to delay the expansion of the variables, which can be done in many different ways:

- call the output command:

  ```
  FOR %%A in (*.css) DO ( 
      call echo %%date%% %%time%% >>log.txt
      pause
  )
  ```

  the code executed will then be like the one you initially wanted to write:

  ```
  FOR %A in (*.css) DO (
      call echo %date% %time%  1>>log.txt
      pause
  )
  ```
- Another, similar possibility is to use call to execute code below a label outside of the loop:

  ```
  FOR %%A in (*.css) DO ( 
      call :printLogEntry
      pause
  )
  exit

  :printLogEntry
      echo %date% %time% >>log.txt
  exit /b
  ```
- And of course you can use delayedExpansion:

  ```
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  FOR %%A in (*.css) DO ( 
      echo !date! !time! >>log.txt
      pause
  )
  ```